# персонаж забирается на отвесные стены

Tags: c#, unity3d

есть персонаж, коробка из стен 90 градусов, и characterController. если подойти к стене боком или передом, то персонаж в нее упрется, а если задом - залезет. коллайдеры менял, толщину кожи пробовал, скрипты менял. не понимаю почему возникает проблема, и почему только при движении назад. а если еще узнаю как решить, то вообще классно будет, но думаю смогу и сам разобраться(если буду знать причину).

вот код движения:

```
float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float moveZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
Vector3 move = transform.right * moveX + transform.forward * moveZ;
controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

и вот код для гравитации:

```
velocity.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
if (grounded && velocity.y < 0)
{
    velocity.y =-1.0f;
}
controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: не нужно гравитацию прописывать кодом. Для этого есть Rigitbody

Comment: а если будет и контроллер и рижидбади, то не будет никаких "артефактов" как например в half life 1 было?

Comment: @Andrew только что убрал код гравитации и поставил rigidbody, теперь персонаж летает по карте и при нажатии esc падает как rigidbody, они вместе не работают

Comment: как минимум потому что движение персонажа реализовано неправильно. Ищи как правильно двигать CharacterController

Comment: ладно, поищу. спасибо за помощь